# TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' and TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have already define `error` initially, but now I don't know why show me error like this

[image]

fetch data from backend code:

`auth.js` file

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";
import { API } from "../config";

export const signup = (user) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/signup`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user),
  })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

I have link connection inside `API` I'm sure is it ok.

After that when i submit my `signup` from then show me error, signup handleSubmit code:

`signupComponent.js` file

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.table({ name, email, password, error, loading, message, showForm });

    setValues({ ...values, loading: true, error: false });
    const user = { name, email, password };

    signup(user).then((data) => {
      try {
        if (data.error) {
          setValues({ ...values, error: data.error, loading: false });
        } else {
          setValues({
            ...values,
            name: "",
            email: "",
            password: "",
            error: "",
            loading: false,
            message: data.message,
            showForm: false,
          });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  };
```

I'm sure my internet connection is ok.
I don't know where is problem.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: can you try with (data & data.error) in try block

Comment: @DarshanSachaniya same problem

Answer (score 1):

You have a chain of callbacks

```
fetch().then().catch()
```

in your `.then()` you return the data but in your `.catch()` you return nothing.
Therefore your outer chain will try to process `undefined` incase the fetching failed.

```
signup().then(
  (data) => ... data.error // data is undefined
)
```

Comment: ok then should I use `.catch((err) => { return err; });` like this !

Answer (score 1):

`auth.js` file updated:

Return the `err` from catch

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";
import { API } from "../config";

export const signup = (user) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/signup`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user),
  })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return err;
    });
};
```

Comment: Now show me `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` this problem, but my internet connect is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve my problem by this way:

1. used `try` `catch` block for find problem
2. In the `catch` block used `.catch((err) => { return err; });`
3. And make sure `API` connected succesfully
4. After that run my backend server

Then run my frontend.